# printing backslash AND unicode characters in one field

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl

let's say I want to print a backslash and the pound symbol on a label: \£
I cant. I can only print either the backslash or the pound symbol, but the other one will render incorrectly.

This will print correctly the pound symbol, but will print a cent symbol instead of the backslash:

^XA
^CI28
^FO^AT^FH^FD_c2_a3^FS
^XZ

And this will print correctly the backslash, but not the pound symbol:

^XA
^CI13
^FO^AT^FH^FD_c2_a3^FS
^XZ

Do you know a way to combine these two in one single field ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Field Hex feature:

^XA
^FO10,10^A0,40,40^FH_^FDEuro Symbol/_15/^FS
^XZ

Comment: Sorry, this is the forward slash. Upon further investigation, I, too, cannot see a way to print both the back slash and other symbols.

Answer (score 2):

As per ZPL script documents, they mentioned "You can mix character sets on a label." using `^CI` command.

But there is no example scripts are available to mix character sets, Instead of that the example scripts are just explaining "how to remap the characters".

Also the document has clearly mentioned that If you want to print backslash, you should use `^CI13`(`^CI13` must be selected to print a backslash (\)). But If we use `^CI13`, Latin characters are not printing properly which expects `^CI28`.

So I'm not sure if it's possible to print both Latin characters and backslash (\) in same label.